# Check If Email alredy exist while user is register ASP.NET CORE MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I am trying to check if User enter existing email addres and display ErrorMessage
So far here is what I do

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new()
            {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                ClientId = Input.ClientId,
                StreetAddress = Input.StreetAddress,
                City = Input.City,
                PostalCode = Input.PostalCode,
                Name = Input.Name,
                PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
                Role = Input.Role,
                Aktivan = false
            };

            var emailExist = _db.ApplicationUsers.Any(x => x.Email == Input.Email);

            if (emailExist)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Korisnicki email vec postoji!");
                return Page();
            }


            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(SD.Role_Admin));
                }

                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Manager))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(SD.Role_Manager));
                }


                if (user.Role == null)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_Manager);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, user.Role);
                }


                //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                //code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                //    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                //    pageHandler: null,
                //    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                //    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                //    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    if (user.Role == null)
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // admin registering new user
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { Area = "Admin" });
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

So I check If email alredy exist

```
var emailExist = _db.ApplicationUsers.Any(x => x.Email == Input.Email);

                if (emailExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Korisnicki email vec postoji!");
                    return Page();
                }
```

And I add also in my Register View

```
<body class="hold-transition register-page">
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="register-logo">
            <a href="~/Home"><b>VmS</b>Group</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
                    <h4>Registracija Korisnika</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ime i Prezime</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Adresa</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.StreetAddress" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.StreetAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Grad</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.City" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.City" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Postanski broj</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Broj telefona</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email adresa</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Lozinka</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Potvrdi lozinku</label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Admin))
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.Role">Korisnicka Uloga</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Input.Role, Model.Input.RoleList,
                           "-Izaberite korisnicku ulogu-", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Input.ClientId">Klijent</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Input.ClientId, Model.Input.ClientList,
                           "-Izaberite klijenta-", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:auto">Nazad</a>
                    }
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registruj se</button>
                    @*<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:auto">Back to User</a>*@
                </form>
                @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Manager))
                {
                    <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" class="text-center">Ukoliko vec imate aktivan korisnicki nalog</a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

But here is problem that I didn't get any erro message in Register page when I enter existing email address. What is wrong here ? Where did I made mistake ?

Comment: `var emailExist = _db.ApplicationUsers.Any(x => x.Email == Input.Email);` can you confirm that this returns `true` on dupe email?

Comment: Sure, here is the image. I enter email which alredy exist in db
https://imgur.com/Xcj3UO7

Comment: And here is when I enter email addres which doesn't exist https://imgur.com/WA9PKC1

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the use of `return Page()`, have been using `return View()`, can you confirm that the `ModelState` ErrorList contains the Email error?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point. What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: So when you add the error `ModelState.AddModelError` it saves it as an item in the ModelState.Errors, I want to confirm that is at least happening. 

Like `ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)`

Comment: Sure. 
Here is screenshot : [1]
https://imgur.com/xVqoYaJ
[2]
https://imgur.com/lfuCM2p

Comment: I think `ModelState.AddModelError("Email"` should be `ModelState.AddModelError("Input.Email"` , I could be completely wrong, just taking a guess. I also think there is a way to refer to the object when using `AddModelError` instead of having to use string as first parameter.

Comment: You mean something like ` var emailExist = _db.ApplicationUsers.Any(x => Input.Email == x.Email);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231108/discussion-between-stuart-and-rayor).

Comment: @Stuart It works right now. 
The problem was here `ModelState.AddModelError("Input.Email", "Korisnicki email vec postoji!");`